# `docker run --rm debian:jessie apt update` does not work on Fedora host

Tags: debian, fedora, apt, docker

I'm having trouble debugging a docker issue. On my machine as host, every `apt`/`apt-get`/`apt-cache` command in the `debian:jessie` image hangs and I can't figure out why.

On other machines with docker, when I run (for example)

```
docker run --rm debian:jessie apt list
```

it takes a few seconds but then the list pops up. On my machine, it just hangs forever (> 30 minutes) and uses a full CPU core.

Any ideas on how to debug this problem?

I'm on a fedora 35 (x86_64) with recent and decent hardware. I've already

- tried to run different commands - all take a CPU core and freeze. I tried at least `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt list`, `apt show apt`, `apt-cache showpkg apt` and certainly a few more I can't remember
- tried to disable selinux via `setenforce 0` on the host, to no effect
- tried to take the network away via the `--network none` arguments to docker, to no effect
- updated my fedora host system, to no effect
- checked that the docker-ce version is the latest stable - it is
- tried it with `docker run --rm debian:latest apt list` (i.e. the latest debian) - this works, but I need the old one (jessie, not latest)
- tried to stop the fedora firewall via `systemctl stop firewalld.service` and restart the docker daemon via `systemctl restart docker` (thanks @rubynorails), to no effect

Any ideas on how to go from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours of more trial and error, another image which worked on a different host brought me on the right track. There seems to be a problem with the default ulimits on fedora [1][2].

The following works fine:

```
docker run --rm --ulimit nofile=10000:10000 -ti debian:jessie apt list
```

I just added the `--ulimit` parameter to every container/docker build and so far everything works like a charm.

[1] https://github.com/coreos/fedora-coreos-docs/issues/103

[2] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1715254

Answer (score 2):

**Edited based on [@jsbillings's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3976/jsbillings) comment below -- please note that based on [@felher's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/524770/felher) feedback, this particular answer did not solve their issue, but it can be applied to users having the same issue description who are running *Docker versions less than v20.0.***

**Original Answer:**

If I recall, Docker doesn't play nice with `firewalld`, which is enabled by default on RHEL-based systems.  If you want to want it to behave more like an Ubuntu system, where `ufw` is disabled by default, then just stop `firewalld`:

`sudo systemctl stop firewalld`

...and [optionally] disable it so this doesn't happen in the future:

`sudo systemctl disable firewalld`

You may also need to restart the docker daemon for good measure:

`sudo systemctl restart docker` or `systemctl restart docker-ce`

Note that I'm not saying this is the best security practice, but personally, coming from an enterprise environment, we always had our instances disable `firewalld` as soon as they were built, because it's much easier to control access policy via network-based firewall rules than host-based rules.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Nice idea, but sadly, it did not work. (tried to do +1, but I have too little reputation ... :( )
I added it to things I've tried above.

Comment: Docker has native firewalld support, so this suggestion only applies to versions less than v20.0 iirc https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/pull/2548